# Creating relationship between MS Access DB and Google Maps API/Fusion Tables?

Tags: google-maps-api, json, ms-access, google-fusion-tables

We are having an issue with a project that we are working on using Google API and M.S Access. Our project goal is to design a web map in Google API where we can select a parcel of land and have all of the information regarding all of the minor variances that are associated with that parcel come up in a pop up window. We have created a google fusion table of the parcels kml and have it show up on our map. Each parcel has a unique ‘ARN’ number that corresponds to the ‘ARN’ number on the minor variances that is associated with that parcel. All of the minor variances are stored in a Microsoft Access table with all of its associated information (ie Roll Number, City, By Law Numberetc). We want to create a relationship between the parcels layer and the minor variance Access database so that when the parcel is clicked on the web map all of the information for the minor variances that are associated with that parcel (based on the shared ‘ARN’ number) come up in the pop up window. We figure we may have to export our Access database as a CSV and bring it into google fusion tables in order to create a relationship. We have provided a visual below on how we would like our information to be displayed.

I created a mock up of how we want the popup windows to look in a very rough form. The fields in the second image are all from the MS Access DB, though not all will be included in the final window.

How do I create this relationship between the parcels kml and our Access database?

[image: Mock up of end goal]

[image: Mock up 2]